# How can I store a Object on database

Tags: smartface.io

I have some web service response and I use "XML DOM Parser" for parse it .I don't use any Dataset or DataTable. Now I need cache the service response when the app closed. So I need store object to database, without dataset.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your response to a file.

For more information about file operations check the link below;

http://www.smartface.io/developer/guides/advanced/file-operations/